# sql statement that requires 2 distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-expressions

i have a table where there's a user_id and a ticket_type. i want to create a sql statement that will return me the the count of each ticket_type that each user_id generate.

i have come up with this but this involves some hard-coding of ticket_type which i'm not fond of.

```
select b.user_id, b.TypeA, B.TypeB, (b.TypeA + b.TypeB) As "Total Tickets" from
(select user_id, 
sum(case when ticket_type = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as "TypeA",
sum(case when ticket_type = '2' then 1 else 0 end) as "TypeB"
from 
database
group by user_id
) as b;
```

is there a better way to do this? it would be really awesome if someone can provide the answer in linq query expression as well.

EDIT 
Sample Output

```
User_ID   Type_A   Type_B   Total
user1       3        5         8
user2       1        2         3        
user3       6        8        14
```

Sample Database Table

```
DECLARE @Users As TABLE
(
    SN int,
    User_ID char(5),
    Ticket_Type int
)

INSERT INTO @Users VALUES
(1, 'user1', 1),
(2, 'user1', 1),
(3, 'user2', 2),
(4, 'user3', 1),
(5, 'user1', 2),
(6, 'user1', 2),
(7, 'user2', 2),
(8, 'user2', 2)
```

Comment: show us some simple sample data and the desired output

Comment: ... best way to show sample data is ddl + dml, so that we can easily test our answers before posting them.

Comment: my apologies,  what u mean by ddl + dml? i have created 2 tables, 1st table to show the desired output, 2nd table to show the database table. do let me know how i can show the sample data and desired output better

Comment: DDL - Data Definition Language - the create statement of your table.
DML - Data Manipulation Language - the insert statements required to populate the sample table.

Comment: please provide sample input and output , you are providing some html table code its confusing

Comment: Check out my edit to your question. This is the best way to provide sample data.

Comment: try this linq from a in db.somename
group a by user_id into b
select new
{
UserId=b.user_id,

   
    TypeA= (
        from x in b
        select x.ticket_type == 1 ? 1 : 0)
        .Sum()
,TypeB= (
        from x in b
        select x.ticket_type == 2 ? 1 : 0)
        .Sum()
};

Comment: thak you so much! @ZoharPeled

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV would you like to submit this as an answer so i can credit you if it's the right answer?

Comment: @user1166085  I didn't check the query, If its solved your problem then i can make it as an answer

Comment: u can add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following linq query.

```
 var result= from a in db.somename group a by user_id into b 
    select new { UserId=b.user_id, 
    TypeA= ( from x in b select x.ticket_type == 1 ? 1 : 0) .Sum() ,
    TypeB= ( from x in b select x.ticket_type == 2 ? 1 : 0) .Sum() };
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to show other possibility, you can try to use PIVOT operator.
You have to define the name only in one place (the pivot operator).  I included a 3rd ticket type for example (plus the column with the total).  If you want avoid NULL and to rename fields (ticket type), you have to use COALESCE and aliases for every single field in the outer SELECT

```
SELECT RC2.* 
FROM
(  select user_id
    , CASE WHEN GROUPING(ticket_type)=1 THEN 'TOT_TCK' ELSE CAST(ticket_type AS VARCHAR(4)) END AS TICKET_TYPE
    , COUNT(*) AS RC 
 from  @USERS
 group by rollup(ticket_type), user_id
 ) A
 PIVOT (SUM(RC) FOR TICKET_TYPE IN ([1],[2],[3],[TOT_TCK])) AS RC2
```

Output:

```
user_id 1           2           3           TOT_TCK
------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
user1   2           2           NULL        4
user2   NULL        3           NULL        3
user3   1           NULL        NULL        1
```

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a table of data to run off, try something like this;

```
--CREATE TABLE #TEMP (User_ID int, type int)
--INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES (1,1),(1,2),(1,2),(1,3),(2,2),(2,4)

SELECT User_id, type, count(User_ID) as count FROM #TEMP
group by user_ID, type
```

I get this;

```
User_id type    count
1       1       1
1       2       2
2       2       1
1       3       1
2       4       1
```

Comment: thank you but this is not the desired output. i have created a html table in my qns above that shows the desired output and the database table! hope its clearer

Comment: why are you posted more than one answer ?if you want to include more then add it in your first answer itself